# How to serialize an object as a soap-encoded xml in .NET Core

Tags: c#, .net, xml, soap, xml-serialization

I want to get soap encoded XML but not sure how. Based on these models, I am able to construct a simple XML:

```
public class GamblerCheckRequestXmlModel
{
     [XmlElement("Kontekst")]
     public BlackListRequestContext BlackListRequestContext { get; set; }

     [XmlElement("PersonInformation")]
     public PersonInformationRequestXmlModel PersonInformationRequestXmlModel { get;set; 
}

public class BlackListRequestContext
{
    [XmlElement("HovedOplysningerType")]
    public BlackListInformationXmlModel BlackListInformationXmlModel { get; set; }
}

public class BlackListInformationXmlModel
{
    [XmlElement("TransaktionsID")]
    public string TransaktionId { get; set; }

    [XmlElement("TransaktionsTid")]
    public DateTime TransactionDate { get; set; }
}

public class PersonInformationRequestXmlModel
{
    public string PersonCPRNumber { get; set; }
}
```

I am using this code

```
using (StringWriter textWriter = new StringWriter())
{
    xmlSerializer.Serialize(textWriter, rofusGamblerCheckRequestXmlModel);
    requestXMLDocument = textWriter.ToString();
}
```

And I'm able to generate this XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<GamblerCheckRequestXmlModel
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <Kontekst>
        <HovedOplysningerType>
            <TransaktionsID>asss</TransaktionsID>
            <TransaktionsTid>2023-07-11T12:24:57.7311239Z</TransaktionsTid>
        </HovedOplysningerType>
    </Kontekst>
    <PersonInformation>
        <PersonCPRNumber>1112221122</PersonCPRNumber>
    </PersonInformation>
</GamblerCheckRequestXmlModel>
```

How can I get the same but soap encoded like this without introducing  corresponding classes

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<soapEnv:Envelope
    xmlns:soapEnv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <soapEnv:Header />
    <soapEnv:Body>
        <ser:GamblerCheckRequest
            xmlns:ser="http://services.lur.skat.dk">
            <Kontekst>
                <ns1:HovedOplysningerType
                    xmlns:ns1="http://skat.dk/begrebsmodel/xml/schemas/kontekst/2007/05/31/">
                    <TransaktionsID>888Test1/1/0001 12:00:00 AMr684166144</TransaktionsID>
                    <TransaktionsTid>1/1/0001 12:00:00 AM</TransaktionsTid>
                </ns1:HovedOplysningerType>
            </Kontekst>
            <PersonInformation>
                <PersonCPRNumber>1611902081</PersonCPRNumber>
            </PersonInformation>
        </ser:GamblerCheckRequest>
    </soapEnv:Body>
</soapEnv:Envelope>
```

Basically I need the same XML just with envelope attributes (body, header and so on)

Comment: After you serialized your data objects that's will be body of SOAP message, then you need to create full SOAP message with Header and body manually there is no way to serialize it